# What does PLT stand for?

Tags: erlang, dialyzer

I've been using Dialyzer (and Dialyxir) on a big Elixir code base, and when I run it, it spits out a bunch of diagnostic information. It references `.plt` files a lot. What does "PLT" stand for in the context of Erlang and Dialyzer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Dialyzer's context, PLT stands for **Persistent Lookup Table** ([link to docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/dialyzer/dialyzer_chapter.html#the-persistent-lookup-table)). It is the data structure that contains inferred and user-annotated (i.e. 'spec-ed') type signatures that Dialyzer is expected to treat as known and correct when analyzing new files.